# Cannot access parent for loop from nested for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, scope

I'm trying to compare the value of an index between two arrays of dictionaries. To accomplish this I'm using a nested for loop. While the loops are iterating properly there is a problem where `firstDataSetNumber` is not iterating inside of the nested for loop (indicated by the second print statement). The first print statement shows that the for loop is iterating properly. What might be causing the value printed from the second `firstDataSetNumber`within the nested for loop to never change, even though it's value in the first print statement shows that it is indeed iterating properly?

```
def processCommandCenterFile(data):
    firstDataSet = data["FirstDataSet"]
    secondDataSet = data["SecondDataSet"]

    # Go through every First Data Set Record
    for firstDataSetRecord in firstDataSet:
        firstDataSetNumber = firstDataSetRecord["KeyOne"].strip()
        matchingSecondDataSetRecord = None

        print(firstDataSetNumber) # Always iterates properly throughout the application

        # Find the Second Data Set record with the KeyTwo number
        for secondDataSetRecord in secondDataSet:
            print(firstDataSetNumber) # Never iterates past the first value
            if secondDataSetRecord["KeyTwo"].strip() == firstDataSetNumber:
                matchingSecondDataSetRecord = secondDataSetRecord

data = {
    "FirstDataSet": CsvToDictionary("first_data_set.csv"),
    "SecondDataSet": CsvToDictionary("second_data_set.csv")
}

processCommandCenterFile(data)
```

I'm expecting the output from both print statements to be the same. However when I run it the first print statement is each item in the index, however the data from the second print statement is stuck on the first item in the list.

The FirstDataSet and SecondDataSet keys store the output of the following function, which loads a CSV and converts it to a dictionary with headers from the CSV as keys.

```
import csv

def CsvToDictionary(path):
    file = open(path, 'r')
    rawCsvArray = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    headers = rawCsvArray.next()
    dataDictionary = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=headers)

    return dataDictionary
```

Heres the CSV that is used to make `FirstDataSet`

```
KeyOne
143739629
143739629
143750196
143750196
143739646
143739646
143739661
143739661
143739718
```

And then the CSV that's used to make `SecondDataSet`

```
KeyTwo
143739629
143739629
143750196
143750196
143739646
143739646
143739661
143739661
143739718
```

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you can also say what contains in `firstDataSet` and `secondDataSet` and the result you want to achieve. There might be a better solution

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates your question. Please include the actual and expected output of your program. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: What output do you expect? From your comments in the code, the code seems to be working properly.

Comment: I'm expecting the output from both print statements to be the same. However when I run it the first print statement is each item in the index, however the data from the second print statement is stuck on the first item in the list.

Comment: I don't see any way that you'd get the results you describe from the code you've shown. Can you perhaps adjust the code so that it can be run without an unspecified `data` value, but so that it still demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Oh, I think one possible way you'd get a weird output would be if `secondDataSet` is an iterator (such as a file), rather than a sequence that can be iterated over several times. Iterators are (generally speaking) single-use, so you usually can't use one as the target of an inner loop. Some specific iterators might give you a way to rewind them (such as `file.seek(0)`), but that's not a normal part of the iterator protocol. Since we don't know anything about `data` though, it's hard to know if this is the issue.

Comment: Hey, the data is being loaded from a CSV with a few hundred thousand values, I'm working to make it a variable and remove the "data" parameter for for the method but it works when it's just a variable not being loaded from a CSV. How would you solve the issue when the data is a dictionary created from a CSV with headers as keys?

Comment: Please see the above changes, is this returning an iterator in stead of a more standard array of dictionaries?

Comment: I've edited the post to include a sample of the CSV's that are being imported along with the function that is creating the dictionaries and the code that is iterating over them.

Comment: You're printing the same thing, `firstDataSetNumber`, in both statements.  Did you intend the second print statement to print something else (perhaps `secondDataSetNumber`)?

Comment: Blckknght, if you write up an answer using the causality you identified within the next two days I'll accept it as an answer so you get credit, otherwise I'm going to accept my own that was made possible by your iteration explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem (thanks to Blckknght), but casting the output for csv.DictReader to a list like so:

```
import csv

def CsvToDictionary(path):
    file = open(path, 'r')
    rawCsvArray = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    headers = rawCsvArray.next()
    dataDictionary = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=headers)

    return list(dataDictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

The practical solution to this question was answered by Kirkland.  Here's a bit of context, should anyone else wind up here.

The issue is that `csv.DictReader()` produces an instance of type `DictReader`, which, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), "operates like a regular reader."
That means that reading values from a `DictReader` depletes the contents of the instance.
After the first round of the inner loop, there's nothing left in `secondDataSet`.  On future iterations, the inner loop doesn't have any elements to iterate over.

This can be verified by adding flags to the `print` statements:

```
def processCommandCenterFile(data):
    ...
    for firstDataSetRecord in firstDataSet:
        ...
        print("first print:", firstDataSetNumber) 

    for secondDataSetRecord in secondDataSet:
        print("second print:", firstDataSetNumber) 
        ...

processCommandCenterFile(data)
```

Output:

```
('first print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('second print:', '143739629')
('first print:', '143739629')
('first print:', '143750196')
('first print:', '143750196')
('first print:', '143739646')
('first print:', '143739646')
('first print:', '143739661')
('first print:', '143739661')
('first print:', '143739718')
```

The best option, as Kirkland noted, is to convert the `DictReader` to a list of dicts, e.g.,

```
list(csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=headers))
```

(Or just use Pandas.)

Answer (score -1):

First data set number looks to be declared before the second one starts.  then each one in the second set should be looking at firstdataset